# Make an animated outlook online signature

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to make an animated outlook signature. I'm definitely a novice coder, but I thought this was a project I could maybe do. I used VS Code to make a basic signature:

```html
<head><style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    @keyframes testt {
        0% {
            width: 0px;
            left: 0;
        }
        50% {
            width: 80px;
            left: 0;
        }
        100% {
            width: 0px;
            left: 80px;
        }
    }
    #aaaa {
        background-color: #00ffff;
        animation: testt 3s ease-in-out infinite;
        height: 33px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

    }
    #aaa {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin-top: 7px;
        margin-left: 7px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="aaa">John Doe</p>
<div id="aaaa"></div>
</body>
```

I used weird names for everything because this was just supposed to be a test run, not to be remembered or kept.

Anyway, I realized how hard it would be when the `position: fixed` caused the blue `<div>` element to go to the very top of the section, not the signature. I got all of the problems ironed out, and it looked perfect in the
[signature area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVcOV.png).

Then, I sent a test email - and only the text showed up where my signature was. I inspected the email and it seemed outlook deleted the div and also changed the ids I had set. The `<style>` I had was also completely gone. What happened, and is there a way to circumvent this to impress my friends with an animated signature?

Answer (score 0):

Animation is not supported on Outlook.com

Source: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-animation/
https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-keyframes/

You would have to make this an animated GIF.